# C++, Can't instantiate abstract class error

Tags: c++

The compiler gives the error cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members:

how do I sort this?

```
'double PayOff::operator ()(const double &) const' : is abstract
```

this the abstract class

```
class PayOff {
public:
    virtual ~PayOff() {}
    virtual double operator()(const double& spot) const = 0;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<PayOff> clone() const = 0;
};
```

derived class is

```
class AsianGeometric: public PayOff{
private:
        double strike;
public:
    AsianGeometric(const double& strike);
    virtual ~AsianGeometric(){};
    virtual double asianpay()(const std::vector<double>& spot_prices) const;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<PayOff> clone()const;
};

AsianGeometric::AsianGeometric(const double& strike){
    this-> strike = strike;
}

double AsianGeometric::asianpay(const std::vector<double>& spot_prices) const{
    unsigned num_times = spot_prices.size();
    double log_sum = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<spot_prices.size(); i++){
        log_sum += log(spot_prices[i]);
    }
    double geom_mean = exp(log_sum/static_cast<double>(num_times));
    if (geom_mean > strike) return geom_mean - strike;
        else return 0;
 }

std::shared_ptr<PayOff> AsianGeometric::clone()const{
    return std::shared_ptr<PayOff>(new AsianGeometric(*this));
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You are aware that:

```
virtual double operator()(const std::vector<double>& spot_prices) const;
```

Does not override:

```
virtual double operator()(const double& spot) const = 0;
```

Right?

Comment: Overload or override?

Comment: @BillLynch I don't see a reason to phrase your answer like this, however trivial the OP's question is. (I'm leaving a comment because I won't go into an edit war).

Comment: @BillLynch should I put that in the abstract class too?

Comment: @j_needs_help: When you have a virtual method that you are overriding in a derived class, the arguments need to match. So you need to ask yourself what API does the base class offer and then implement that in the derived classes.

Comment: @j_needs_help: In your current code, Your derived class `AsianGeometric` doesn't implement an `operator()(double const &)`. So it is still an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

To instantiate the derived class `AsianGeometric`, it needs some implementation of the following all the pure virtual functions in the base class.

```
virtual double operator()(const double& spot) const = 0;
virtual std::shared_ptr<PayOff> clone() const = 0;
```

That is, something like the following.

```
class AsianGeometric: public PayOff{
private:
    double strike;
public:
    AsianGeometric(const double& strike);
    virtual ~AsianGeometric(){};
    virtual double operator()(const double& spot) const {
      // put implementation here
    }
    virtual std::shared_ptr<PayOff> clone() const {
      // put implementation here
    }
```

Note that the implementation may be put inline in the class body or offline, it does not matter, the important point is that the method signatures must **exactly** match.

In addition, in C++11, as a good designer, you can use the `override` keyword to indicate the compiler that your intention is to override. That way, if the signature of the derived method has **any** difference with the signature of the base class, then the compiler would flag it as an error.

That is,

```
virtual double operator()(const double& spot) const ovrerride;
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```